# How can I avoid creating a new cursor object repeatedly while counting features in a large SDE Database?

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, performance

I would like to get a script running much faster than it is now. The script completes on my machine in about 33 minutes. It generates a report that counts features with specific attributes in one field.  What I think is generally the problem to be solved is that there are 7 features classes in 70+ datasets, with 4 possible entries in the field that I want counted separately.

Here is a very reduced and plain version of the code, it shows generally the structure of the nested cursor in some nested for loops.  I wonder if it is possible to NOT have the cursor creation be this nested??

```
state_plane_list = [...]
feature_class_list = ['PRCL_POL_',...]
clause = ["RESEARCH_STATUS = 'NULL'",...]

for state_plane in state_plane_list:
     for feature_class in feature_class_list:
          for rstatus in clause:
               cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(feature_class + state_plane, fields, str(rstatus))  
                       ***Counting code here - everything ends up in a dictionary and eventually gets written to a csv using DictWriter() ****
```

Basically, is there another...hopefully more efficient... way to do this?? I feel like creating 1600+ cursor objects may be way too dense a procedure.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you are searching your entire dataset for each combination. You would probably find it quicker to use a view of state_plane, from that create a view of feature_class_list, etc.

*N.B. View might be the wrong terminology for this database - it's been a while since my DB centric work - look at creating a query that creates a subset to search.*